# Read only a fixed column width in a text file in C

Tags: c, variables, text-files

Let's say I have this text file `data.txt`:

```
|-- 20 characters--||-- 20 characters--|
Carlos              Rivera Bernal 
Thomas              James Hanner
James               Patrick Sullivan
Brayan              Williams
Khaterine           Smith
Ben                 Thompson
```

How could you read a text file with only the first column of fixed width. After storing each row in that column into a variable and use it as a parameter to a function.

Comment: Is first column fixed width ? Because i think it's not 20 characters wide, or do you mean has maximum width ? Or you just want to read until newline character appears ?

Comment: I mean the maximum width.

Answer (score 5):

If your lines were consistently padded to 40 characters plus newline, you could use `%20c` to read each 20-character field.  That would save the blanks and all; you could strip those off afterwards if you wish.  Note that this does not null terminate the strings; you have to do that.

```
char first[21];
char last[21];

while (scanf(" %20c %20c", first, last) == 2)
{
    first[20] = last[20] = '\0';
    printf("[%s] [%s]\n", first, last);
}
```

With properly formatted data, this produces:

```
[Carlos              ] [Rivera Bernal       ]
[Thomas              ] [James Hanner        ]
[James               ] [Patrick Sullivan    ]
[Brayan              ] [Williams            ]
[Khaterine           ] [Smith               ]
[Ben                 ] [Thompson            ]
```

However, if the second field is not padded to (at least) 20 characters, the `%20c` will consume the newline and start of the next line:

```
[Carlos              ] [Rivera Bernal 
Thoma]
[s              James] [Hanner
James        ]
[Patrick Sullivan
Bra] [yan              Wil]
[liams
Khaterine     ] [Smith
Ben           ]
```

Your next choice, which works on the given data, is:

```
while (scanf(" %20[^ ] %20[^\n]", first, last) == 2)
    printf("[%s] [%s]\n", first, last);
```

It reads up to 20 characters (or the first blank) in the first field, then up to 20 characters (or the newline) in the second field.  On my copy of your data, that produced:

```
[Carlos] [Rivera Bernal ]
[Thomas] [James Hanner]
[James] [Patrick Sullivan]
[Brayan] [Williams]
[Khaterine] [Smith]
[Ben] [Thompson]
```

There must be a trailing blank after Carlos's name and not anyone else's.  You could combine the techniques to read a 'first name' that has blanks in it:

```
while (scanf(" %20c %20[^\n]", first, last) == 2)
{
    first[20] = last[20] = '\0';
    printf("[%s] [%s]\n", first, last);
}
```

which yields:

```
[Carlos              ] [Rivera Bernal ]
[Thomas              ] [James Hanner]
[James               ] [Patrick Sullivan]
[Brayan              ] [Williams]
[Khaterine           ] [Smith]
[Ben                 ] [Thompson]
```

You could write a function to null trailing blanks.  For example:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void null_trailing_blanks(char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    assert(buflen > 0);
    buffer[--buflen] = '\0';
    while (buflen > 0 && buffer[buflen-1] == ' ')
        buffer[--buflen] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char first[21];
    char last[21];

    while (scanf(" %20c %20c", first, last) == 2)
    {
        null_trailing_blanks(first, sizeof(first));
        null_trailing_blanks(last, sizeof(last));
        printf("[%s] [%s]\n", first, last);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On the fully-padded data set, that yields:

```
[Carlos] [Rivera Bernal]
[Thomas] [James Hanner]
[James] [Patrick Sullivan]
[Brayan] [Williams]
[Khaterine] [Smith]
[Ben] [Thompson]
```

Comment: I have a cuestion,
What makes this line :while (scanf(" %20c %20c", first, last) == 2)     ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'what make this line'?  Are you asking about the `== 2`? Or the details of the format string? Or something else?

Comment: You need to read the manual on [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html).  Expect to need to read it half a dozen times in the first week before you understand about 80% of it; read it another dozen times in the next month to get to 90-95%; then read it at least yearly to maintain that level.  It is a function that's incredibly difficult to understand.  I wish it wasn't taught in beginning courses, but … _[…continued…]_

Comment: In short, the `scanf()` functions return the number of successful conversions (which may be from zero up to the number of assigning conversions). Assigning conversions are those not spelled `%n` and those not containing an asterisk (such as `%*c`). If you expect two values, check that you got two values.  If you didn't, something went wrong. It is often better to use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) and parse with `sscanf()` — at least you can retry.

Comment: And if I want to store data of the first column into variables, how could I do this?

Comment: Waddya mean?  It's already stored in a variable — `first`.  If you want to store it in a different variable, define the alternative variable, making sure there's enough space allocated, and then either read direct into the other variable or copy from `first` into the other variable.

Comment: store each element of the column into a different variable

Comment: Since you're going to have multiple names, your best bet (if you've got far enough in your studies) would be a structure type such as `struct Name { char first[21]; last[21]; };`, and then have an array of those structures: `struct Name names[30];`, and a function `int read_name(struct Name *name)` which would read the data for a single row into the structure it is passed returning a boolean true if it read a name and false if not, and a loop such as `for (i = 0; i < 30 && read_name(&names[i]); i++) ;`  (an empty loop body).  Using functions is almost always one of the key steps.